# MySQL search with joins and match

Tags: php, mysql, join, match, against

I've got one table filled with information about companies (tblforetag) in Sweden, one table with provinces (tbllan) and one table with cities (tblstad). The cities are linked to the provinces with id numbers and the company table has a column for the city name (varchar).

How do I search for all the companies in one province?

I have fiddled around with joins but not got it to work. I've got this code right now that works but it will only search for company names and cities (in the company table):

```
$sql = "
    SELECT *, 
    MATCH(tblforetag.foretag) AGAINST(:keywords) AS kr
    FROM tblforetag
    WHERE MATCH(tblforetag.foretag) AGAINST(:keywords)
    ";
$sql .= $locisset ? "AND tblforetag.stad LIKE :location" : "";
$sql .= " LIMIT $offset, $rpp"; 
$query = $conn->Prepare($sql);
$query->BindValue(':keywords', $keywords);
if($locisset) $query->BindValue(':location', "%$location%");
$query->Execute();
```

Comment: $locisset is a boolean variable telling me wether a location criteria has been given or not.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your table structure but something along these lines shoulod do the trick:

```
SELECT FROM companies 
LEFT JOIN cities ON (companies.city_id = cities.id)
LEFT JOIN regions ON (cities.region_id = regions.id)
WHERE region.name = 'your region'
```

This would give you the companies in that particular region.

Comment: This is what I've tried but it always gives me ALL companies or no matches at all. I'm gonna look into this once again.

Comment: In your Result, you should have the region.name field as well. Due to SQL Syntax, entries that have a region.name other than 'your region' would not fit and therefore can't be in the result. Maybe your relations are not working?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding you here. Of course I've replaced 'your region' with something apropriate. This is what I have now:

`SELECT *, 
MATCH(tblforetag.foretag) AGAINST(:keywords) AS kr
FROM tblforetag
LEFT JOIN tblstad ON tblforetag.stad = tblstad.Stad LEFT JOIN tbllan ON tbllan.Id = tblstad.Lan_id
WHERE MATCH(tblforetag.foretag) AGAINST(:keywords)
AND (tblforetag.stad LIKE :location OR tbllan.Lan LIKE :location)`

This does not return anything.

Comment: Just for testing purposes, try leavin the MATCH out of it and use the simple WHERE tbllan.Lan LIKE :location Syntax.
Just to see if your JOINS are right.

Comment: I found the problem. The tables for some reason had different default collations and therefore did not give any results. As a matter of fact, it outputted an error I didn't try/catch.

Comment: @Perplexor Consider accepting one of the two Answers or ask for further Detail. This will prevent this Question from getting any more Attention and also show at least some appreciation for the people who took the time to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better the city_name column in companies table to city_id.

```
SELECT a.*, p.provincename
FROM   companies a, cities c, provinces p
WHERE a.city_name = c.city_name
AND      c.city_id = p.city_id
AND      p.province_id = 5 // give your province id here
```

Comment: I'm aware of this but this database holds reused data and contains over a million rows. It's not doable.

Comment: @Perplexor ok. What about the query?

Comment: I rewrote the query to match my tables and input fields, like this:

 SELECT tblforetag.*,
 tbllan.Lan, 
 MATCH(tblforetag.foretag) AGAINST(:keywords) AS kr
 FROM tblforetag, tblstad, tbllan
 WHERE MATCH(tblforetag.foretag) AGAINST(:keywords)
 AND (tblforetag.stad LIKE :location
  OR (tblforetag.stad = tblstad.Stad AND tblstad.Lan_id = tbllan.Id AND tbllan.Lan = :location)
 )

But it still gives no results.